# Remove a specific tag and replace it with awk

Tags: html, awk, sed

I'm using a tool to generate some html that looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<style>
/* stuff */
</style>
</head>
```

But I'd like a way to replace that style tag with some custom styling

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

possibly with `awk` or `sed` so that I can add it to my Makefile.
Is this possible?

Comment: Fix that tool which is generating the wrong html

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

This is not xml/html aware but a basic text substitution...

```
$ awk '/<style>/   {f=1} 
       !f;
       /<\/style>/ {f=0; 
                    print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">"}' file
```

will give

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: How would it look for it to match to `<style type="text/css">`? I can't seem to escape the double quotes with any number of `\"`s

Comment: no need to escape double quotes in pattern, but you need to escape slash with a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

If you like tricks, check also this out:

```
$ ht=$'<html>\n<head>\n<title>Blah</title>\n<style>\n/* stuff */\n</style>\n</head>\n'
$ st=$'<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">'

$ echo "$ht"
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<style>
/* stuff */
</style>
</head>

$ echo "$ht" |perl -0777 -pe "s/\n/\0/g;s/<style>.*<\/style>/$st/g;s/\0/\n/g"
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<style>
/* stuff */
</style>
</head>'|sed -e '/<style>/{:a;/<\/style>/!{N;ba};c <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">' -e'}'
<html>
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

@mef51: try: taking adaption from karafka's nice code, only thing is this code will print  and  tags too along with your new line.

```
awk '/<style>/   {print;f=1}
       !f;
       /<\/style>/ {f="";
                    print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\">" ORS $0}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** searching for string  and then set variable f's value to ON/TRUE/one(1) and then checking condition !f if variable f's value is NULL(when line doesn't have  or  it will be NULL) so print the current line. now looking for string  and printing the new line along with ORS(Output field separator, whose default value is new line) and the current line.